# Add two decimal number in bash script

Tags: bash, decimal, addition

How can I add two decimal number in bash??
For instance this

```
LAT=37.748944
LNG=-122.4175548
D=0.01

somecommand --position "$(( LAT + D )), $(( LNG + D ))"
```

fails with

```
37.748944: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".748944")
```

Comment: `$((...))` only does integer arithmetic; the proposed duplicate is about the external command `expr`, but the same restrictions apply to both.

Comment: For an exhaustive exploration of how to do floating point math in shell, see ["How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `bc`, it should work with decimal calculations:

```
LAT=37.748944
LNG=-122.4175548
D=0.01

somecommand --position "$(echo "$LAT + $D" | bc), $(echo "$LNG + $D" | bc)"
```

Comment: fyi, you don't need that echo, you can just pass strings directly into commands: `bc <<< "$LAT + $D"`